# Each, attr, or this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, this, attr

I'm not sure if I need the `each()` function here or if I can somehow do this with `this`. I'm trying to switch the src attribute based on the `if` statement. It works except that it switches them both to `hifi1.jpg`. How do I make it so it applies each `img`'s `data-websrc` value to itself?

HTML:

```
<img class="airsrc" src="lofi1.jpg" data-websrc="hifi1.jpg" alt="example1">
<img class="airsrc" src="lofi2.jpg" data-websrc="hifi2.jpg" alt="example2">
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var airsrc = $('.airsrc');
    airsrc.each(function() {
        if ( Modernizr.mq('(min-width:480px)') ) { 
            var src = $(this).data('websrc'); 
            airsrc.attr('src', src);
        }
    });
});
```

Update: Solution:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if ( Modernizr.mq('(min-width:480px)') ) { 
    $('.airsrc').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var src = $this.data('websrc');
        if ( src != '' ) { 
            $this.attr('src', src);
        }
    });
    }
});
```

That works in browsers that support custom data attributes, which from my testing I've found to mean FF/Chrome/Opera/Safari. Maybe IE9. I think getAttribute can be used though for (older) IE.

Comment: Why do you think that `$(this).data('websrc');` will return the value of the image's `data-websrc` attribute (which is an invalid attribute anyway, but that is a different matter)?

Comment: `each`, `attr` and `this` are completely orthogonal.

Comment: The reason that code is buggy is because you're calling `airsrc.attr()` instead of `$(this).attr()` inside your each() loop, therefore it sets the attribute on everything in the collection as opposed to the specific element.

Comment: @Delan: Valid in HTML5, and jQuery [has supported this since 1.4.3](http://api.jquery.com/data/).

Comment: @Chris: Why is that a comment? o.O

Comment: because someone else had already written the correct solution. I was merely providing an explanation.

Comment: Mmmm ok. Think it was an answer. Never mind!

Comment: Tomalak, that's very interesting and I didn't know such a thing existed. Thanks! By the way, where is this in the HTML5 spec?

Comment: @Delan: [3.2.3.8 Embedding custom non-visible data with the data-* attributes](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#custom-data-attribute). Is your Ctrl+F broken? :(

Comment: @Tomalak From my testing I've found that this method of reading the custom HTML5 data attributes works in FF/Chrome/Safari/Opera but not IE. I guess `getAttribute` would be needed for IE, right?

Comment: @ryanve: I have no IE knowledge, sorry. It may just be that IE doesn't properly implement this part of HTML5 yet.

Comment: @Tomalak I'd also tried the `dataset` method, but didn't get it to work. I haven't found a definitive answer on where that is supported, but I wasn't getting it to work so I went with the jQuery `data()`

Comment: @Tomalak Having no IE knowledge is a good thing! ;)  (Much of the HTML5 stuff works in IE9 but not earlier.)

Comment: Correction: This *might* work in IE9. I haven't been able to properly test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var $this = $(this),
    src = $this.data('websrc'); 
$this.attr('src', src);
```

It was applying to both, because you were applying it to the whole jQuery object `airsrc`.

You had to specifically reference the current element with `$(this)`

or...

Do it like the above code, which assigns `$(this)` to `$this` in order to cache it, for avoiding further lookups. Then you get its data and change its attribute.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to use `this` inside the each to get the specific item for that iteration, wrapped in jQuery, of course.  With some small optimizations...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if (Modernizer.mq('(min-width:480px)')) {
        $('.airsrc').each(function() {
           var $this = $(this),
                 src = $(this).data('websrc'); 
           $this.attr('src', src);
       });
    }
});
```

Note that if you check the condition outside the `each`, you only have to do it once.  Also, you can avoid reconstituting the jQuery of `this` by assigning it to a variable then reusing it.

Comment: I performed a few small optimisations of my own. Notably, making the thing work.. :)

Comment: @Tomalek - ah, I see I cut out the `.` when I elided the lines.  Thanks for fixing!

Comment: @Tomalak Thank you! Yes, the faster the better! The idea was to probably have two or three if statements based on mobile, tablet, or web. I figure I also need to add a check to make sure data-websrc is not null. (version added above)

Answer (score 2):

`airsrc.attr('src', src);` should be `$(this).attr('src', src);` and everything will be wonderful

Answer (score 1):

You can make your code a lot shorter by using a feature of the attr method:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    if ( Modernizr.mq('(min-width:480px)') ) { 
        $('.airsrc').attr('src', function() {
            return $(this).data('websrc');
        });
    }
});
```